# To can I find out the selected range in pixels?

Tags: photoshop, pixel, cm

How can I find out the selected region in pixels in Photoshop? By default its showing in centimeters. I want to know the selected range in pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to units setting through

Edit > Preferences > Unit and Rulers

You can set it to pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to change the way units are displayed is right clicking the guide rulers at the top or side of the canvas. Command-R toggles the guide rulers.